# How can I print `self` using the Debug formatter in a trait's default method?

Tags: rust

I defined a trait:

```
pub trait SaySomething {
    fn say(&self) {
        println!("{:?} can't speak", self);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error[E0277]: `Self` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:38
  |
3 |         println!("{:?} can't speak", self);
  |                                      ^^^^ `Self` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `Self`
  = help: consider adding a `where Self: std::fmt::Debug` bound
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `&Self`
  = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
```

So I tried:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub trait SaySomething {
    fn say<Self: Debug>(self: &Self) {
        println!("{:?} can't speak", self);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: expected identifier, found keyword `Self`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:12
  |
4 |     fn say<Self: Debug>(self: &Self) {
  |            ^^^^ expected identifier, found keyword

error[E0194]: type parameter `Self` shadows another type parameter of the same name
 --> src/lib.rs:4:12
  |
3 | / pub trait SaySomething {
4 | |     fn say<Self: Debug>(self: &Self) {
  | |            ^^^^ shadows another type parameter
5 | |         println!("{:?} can't speak", self);
6 | |     }
7 | | }
  | |_- first `Self` declared here

error[E0307]: invalid method receiver type: &Self
 --> src/lib.rs:4:31
  |
4 |     fn say<Self: Debug>(self: &Self) {
  |                               ^^^^^
  |
  = note: type must be `Self` or a type that dereferences to it
  = help: consider changing to `self`, `&self`, `&mut self`, or `self: Box<Self>`
```

Comment: Your trait has to implement `Debug`: `pub trait SaySomething : std::fmt::Debug { ... }`

Comment: @belst make that an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrict your trait to types that implement `Debug`.

```rust
pub trait SaySomething: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn say(&self) {
        println!("{:?} can't speak", self);
    }
}
```